# how to get array value in function in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

```
 <select class="form-control" id="column" ng-model="selectedcolumn" ng-options="column for column in columns"></select>    
 <input type="text" ng-model="test[selectedcolumn]" ng-change="search()" />
```

how to get this ng-model="test[selectedcolumn]"  value ,something like this:

```
  $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.names, function (item) {
                        for (var attr in item) {

                            if (searchMatch(item[attr], $scope.test))
                                return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
```

Comment: Where would you want to get that value? In your controller I guess? The way to get it depends on where you want to use it.

Comment: yes sir, i want to use in controller

Comment: exactly i am using it for search

Comment: Then could you add you controller code here? Or create a Plunkr out of it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You just pasted the code of an Angular filter, not a controller.

Comment: Code in question makes no sense . Provide a proper problem description and more code context

Comment: yes sir ,i want to use it for angular  filter .........sorry sir for my inappropiate question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work. 
Just try this on your view.

```
<select class="form-control" id="column" ng-model="selectedcolumn" ng-options="column for column in columns" ng-change="search(this)"></select>
```

Just try this on your JS file. And just append the selected value to the input model

```
var search = function (selectedValue) { 
   console.log (selectedValue);
   test = selectedValue;
}
```

It will give you the values of the selected item from the dropdown.

Comment: do you know what `this` is in the `ng-change`? It's defintiely not what you think it is

Answer (score 0):

from your controller you'd have to use scope to access both variables, like this:

```
$scope.search = function() { 
   console.log($scope.test[$scope.selectedcolumn]);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/n4FxNt06N5HrNoY3Y77Y?p=preview

Comment: but this error came "Cannot read property 'CustomerID' of undefined" customerID is the $scope.selectedcolumn

Comment: that means that `$scope.test` is not defined in the scope of where you are trying to access it for some reason